# How to categorise (filter) data in java 8

Tags: java, collections, filtering

I have class with data points. Class is defined as follows:

```
public class ExciseReportDataPoint {
    private String liquorCategoryName;
    private String liquorName;
    private String nozzleName;
    private String bottleExciseNumber;
    private int fixedPegSize;
    private double costPerPeg;
    private int bottleSize;
    private int consumedVolumeInMl;
    private int volumeInBottleInMl;
    private boolean isBottleEmpty;
    private int totalNoOfPegsPoured;
    private double totalSaleValue;
    // Getters and setters for all

}
```

I am getting `List<ExciseReportDataPoint>` from my API. I want to show tabular report where rows has to categorised first with LiquorCategory and then Liquor.

I want to convert `List<ExciseReportDataPoint>` to `Map<String, Map <String, List<List<String>>>>`. I am not sure whether it is possible or not by using *stream* and *collectors*

Does anyone have take on this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group your list several times:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<ExciseReportDataPoint>>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ExciseReportDataPoint::getLiquorCategoryName, Collectors.groupingBy(ExciseReportDataPoint::getLiquorName)));
```